# Separation of Activities between phones and tablets (io2012 app)

Tags: android

I've seen in sources of IO2012 application that guys are separating `Activity` classes in their `ui` package for `tablets` and `phones`. Is it kind of good practice we also need follow? Actually don't really find it useful, what for?

Comment: If your phone/tablet app has different functionality in the same activity then yes, it is a good idea rather than having both jammed into one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android team was very specific when they stated that this application is the current best practices example for Android. So yes, you should do what they are doing whenever it is fitting for your needs.